# Conditional formatting using countif() with values from an external spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet the references values from another and using conditional formatting, it marks down the cells with the same value. Within the same document, I use the following code:
`=countif(indirect("Responses!D2:D103"),A1)=1` That works great.

However, I try to get the same result referencing the same sheet from an external spreadsheet to no avail. I feel like I tried all the combinations of IMPORTRANGE and INDIRECT out there, similar to this: `=countif(importrange("sheet_url",indirect("Responses!$D$2:$D$103")),A1)=1`

I'm sure I'm missing some small detail, I just can't tell what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIF(IMPORTRANGE("1ddqnVB9eDkk2tCadotN0NQlZdJDzIX4UyEEuXVs99nk", 
 "Responses!D1:D103"), A1)=1)
```

[image]

note that access needs to be granted first in order for this to work

Comment: Thank you. That didn't solve the problem for me. I'm pretty sure it has access, I remember the sheet asking for permission at one point. I don't know where to check, however.

Comment: once you paste `=IMPORTRANGE("sheet_url", "Responses!D2")` in any cell and it wont ask for access then you granted the permission

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheets?

Comment: Yeah, it definitely has access granted. I did a test below the main table. Here's a link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QCYb08PEY1vur1KjSOJHlXKBzsj-R-3CPhxgATk9IrQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That's awesome, thank you! So it doesn't need the entire URL, just the identifier. Thank you again!